# SetText() on AutoCompleteTextView overrides setAdapter()

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have an adapter which displays a number of contacts. When a contact is clicked, the Contact activity is brought up to display all the contact info. Some of this info is the phone type (work, home, other).

I am using setText() on the AutoCompleteTextView to show the phone type stored in the database, but when I proceed to click on the ACTV, the dropdown menu only shows the saved value as an option.

Could it be that setText() cannot be used along with setAdapter()? I believe this is causing the error, because if I use setAdapter() only, the dropdown menu works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

That was easier than I thought. The "bug" was due to filtering, so all that was needed was to disable it using "false" as the 2nd argument of setText():

```
myAutoCompleteTextView.setText(arrayList.get(i), false);
```